# How to avoid system update for Samsung Galaxy Note 4?

Tags: ota-update, samsung-galaxy-note-4

My Galaxy Note 4 automatically downloaded the new system update and reminds way too often to install it. I don't want to. How could I avoid it without rooting the phone since I do not want to lose my warranty? Or am I absolutely forced to update?

My hypothesis was that maybe, if I do the factory data reset, it will delete the system update install-file (which should be located in the cache folder, I think).

And after that, if I get rid of the file (by factory data reset or otherwise), is there any way I could block my phone from downloading it again?

Thank you!

Comment: In the **Settings -> Apps -> All Apps**, do you have an entry with system update or similar. If you have it, see if it has the option to disable it. Some ROMs have this option to disable System Update without being rooted. Don't know about Samsung though.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to disable OTA's, all depending on your particular device and AOS version etc. However, most ways require you to be root. Then the most easy way is to use the package managers built-in *block* function, which blocks packages. Use it like: `pm block <package name>`. E.g. `pm block com.sec.android.fotaclient`, would block the *FotaClient.apk*. Often there are various scripts available, that runs through a list of these packages, specific to your device. Or you can also use great apps like *[App Quarantine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramdroid.appquarantine), [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)* or by using some Windows tool like [Debloater](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/debloater-remove-carrier-bloat-t2998294?nocache=1). You can also edit the file extension of the OTA certificate to prevent installs. (Sorry, forgot the exact path and file name.)